# infinite loop on loading workDays ejs-schedule

Tags: html, angular, typescript, syncfusion

I am trying to load working days through a function, I need to load days by calling a function so that I can validate which days it works.

For all other parameters I can execute the method call waiting for logic processing and data return, only the `[workDays]` parameter is looping.

If I create a public variable with a list it works, but I need to execute the method call to execute logic and then return a list.

**component.ts:**

```
  public getWorkDays() {

    // Even returning the ready list it is in a loop updating the calendar.
    let workDays = [1,2,3];
    return workDays;
  }
```

**component.html:**

```
         <ejs-schedule #scheduleObj width='100%' [views]="scheduleViews" [timeScale]="getTimeScale()"
            [workDays]="getWorkDays()" locale="pt" [showWeekend]="showWeekend" [startHour]="getStartHour(product)"
            [endHour]="getEndHour(product)" height='450' [currentView]="'Week'" [selectedDate]="selectedDate"
            [eventSettings]="eventSettings" [rowAutoHeight]="true">
          </ejs-schedule>
```

Comment: This is what happens with calling functions in template. You just shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code example to overcome the reported issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvhguq-r6jesc?file=app.component.ts

```
import { Component,ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

    selector: 'app-root',

    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',

    providers: [WeekService, MonthService, ResizeService, DragAndDropService],

    **changeDetection**: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```